# Nuxt.js project build not generated on server

Tags: ubuntu, nuxt.js

In the `nuxt.js` project, build is not generated using NPM run build

I have tried to remove the node_modules directory and `package-lock.json` and run `NPM` install again

```
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                                           11:02:43
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                                                          11:02:44

● Client █████████████████████████ building (31%) 177/199 modules 22 active
 ...vue

◯ Server



 ERROR  (node:9459) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on .hooks instead                                             11:02:47

Killed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! Moadaty@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Moadaty@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-06-17T11_02_57_028Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try running `node --trace-depracation` to find the deprecated package.

Comment: I have tried that but it says node: bad option: --trace-depracation

Comment: aparently, this is a known issue: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/185

Comment: I have already check that. In my local same DeprecationWarning error occur but build is generated.